# Gmail signature gets deformed

Tags: php, html, css, gmail

I made a new email signature for the company that I am working at. And everyone changed their email signature to the new one that I made. Nobody had issues besides one!

When he copied the signature form the program to gmail everything looked fine. And even when the changes where saved everything still looked fine. But after having the changes saved and trying to compose a new email, the signature gets displayed horizontally instead of the text being below each other. And the line in between the logo and the text disappeared.

Here I have a example of how the signature should look:
[The signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp2zx.png)

And here is how the signature looks when composing a new email:
[The deformed signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU6Wy.png)

As you can see its completely deformed and is not as it should be.

I hope somebody is familiar with this problem and can help me solve it, so that this person can also enjoy the new email signature.

Note: this only happend on one of the 25 people wo changed their email signature to the new one. All the others have had no problems and their email signature works just fine.

Thank you!

Comment: You have a typo in your question title.

Comment: Changed it! thank you.

Comment: Probably it is something with HTML vs Richtext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the specific user settings for the text and formatting. It seems that the user formatting settings are different than other 24 users. 
Also, try to convert this sig to image which which will not be deformed and will look good too.

hope this helps :)

Comment: I will have a look at his settings then. Thank you!